# Placing a Facebook SDK button in a subview in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I would like to place a Facebook share button (could have been a like or a send button) in a subview of my main view, something that appears in the bottom quarter of the screen. The subview appears fine and is big enough to hold the button - see the red portion in the screenshot below. But for some reason the button appears on the top left of the screen, at the offset -70,-452. It is as if the button handling code decides to render the button at the top left irrespective of where it was rendered.

Any ideas on how I could move it to where I need it?

This is the code I am using to bring up the button:

```
 FBSDKSharePhotoContent *content = [[FBSDKSharePhotoContent alloc] init];
 content.photos = @[photo];
 content.contentURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"xxx"];

 FBSDKShareButton *button = [[FBSDKShareButton alloc] init];
 button.shareContent = content;

 [self.shareContainer addSubview:button];
```

[image: Screenshot].

Answer (score 1):

You should try this button.center = self.shareContainer.center.
Your basically trying to set the center of the button to that of its container.

Comment: I actually did already try that, but it did not change anything, so I left it out of the pasted code.

Comment: Did you try to do that after you added the subview ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. My Facebook code was in `viewDidLoad` - meaning that at the time that it was executed autolayout had not taken effect, and the container view had not found its place on the screen. The solution was to put the same code in viewDidLayoutSubviews.